# How to test Angular 2 two way binding input value

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to write a test for my component to test that angular two way binding is working.

On one side I have a test that looks like that (and it passes):

```
it('should bind displayed value to the SearchComponent property', () => {
    searchComponent.searchBoxValue = 'abc';
    searchCompFixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputEl.nativeElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-model')).toBe('abc');
});
```

where

```
searchCompFixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
inputEl = searchCompFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#search-box-input'));
```

and

```
<input
    id="search-box-input"
    [(ngModel)]="searchBoxValue"\>
```

On the other hand I want to write a test that sets the value of the input element first and checks that `SearchComponent` property value has changed. My attempt:

```
it('should bind SearchComponent property to the displayed value', fakeAsync(() => {
    inputEl.nativeElement.value = 'abc';
    let evt = new Event('input');
    inputEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(evt);

    tick();

    searchCompFixture.detectChanges();
    expect(searchComponent.searchBoxValue).toBe('abc');
}));
```

but this doesn't work because `searchComponent.searchBoxValue` value does not get set. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that you need to `detechtChanges` before updating the value of the input field (idk why). Here is the working test:

```
it('should bind SearchComponent property to the displayed value', fakeAsync(() => {
    searchCompFixture.detectChanges();

    inputEl.nativeElement.value = 'abc';
    let event = new Event('input');
    inputEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);

    tick();
    expect(searchCompFixture.componentInstance.searchBoxValue).toEqual('abc');
}));
```

**EDIT**:
I found another improvement for the test `should bind displayed value to the SearchComponent property`. What I didn't like about it was that I used weird angular attribute `ng-reflect-model` and not the normal way `inputEl.nativeElement.value`. The problem with this was that `value` does not get set yet by angular.

Changing the test to the following solves the problem and no magic needed anymore - hoorah!

```
it('should bind displayed value to the SearchComponent property', fakeAsync(() => {
    searchComponent.searchBoxValue = 'abc';

    searchCompFixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    searchCompFixture.detectChanges();


    expect(inputEl.nativeElement.value).toBe('abc');
}));
```